# If possible: How to write a Word Macro which swap the content of the two textboxes on an active page?

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I have a Word Document which creates indexcards for books via series. On every page information about a single book. Sometimes two fields have to be swaped for a specific item. So for my collegue it would save a lot of work if that would be possible with a single click. I have programming experience but not so much Office and no VBA.
Is it possible to do something like below? :

```
Pseudo code:
dim temp as string
dim temp2 as string
select first textbox on active page
temp = select.Text
select second textbox on active page
temp2 = select.Text
select.Text = temp
select first textbox on active page
select.Text = temp2
```

Any ideas what functions to look in would be welcome. Especialy if it is possible to select the first and second textbox of a single (active) page.

Comment: Firstly, what is meant by "textbox"? Word has at least five things that can be called "textbox". If you don't know the technical term, what command is used to create one in the document?

Comment: Secondly, post a screen shot (use the [edit] link below the question to include it in the question) so that we can *see* the situation.

Comment: Then, if Drawing Object text boxes are meant, I strongly suggest finding an alternative. A table with two cells, for example. Drawing object textboxes are notoriously difficult to determine their "order", as how they appear on the page may have nothing to do with Word's internal ordering (indexing).

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a better way to do this, but textboxes in word I find to be a real pain.

Here we set the names of the boxes, how you determine the order I'm unsure, maybe a check using titles, or the anchor point. The ID property is not the index so we can't use that.

```
Sub Rename()
    Dim textbox As Object
    Dim iter As Long
    iter = 1
    For Each textbox In ActiveDocument.Shapes 'I'm not sure how to set names manually
        textbox.Name = "TextBox " & iter
        iter = iter + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Assuming you have the boxes named in the order they appear:

```
Sub TextSwap()
    Dim targetbox As Long
    Dim val1 As String
    Dim val2 As String

    targetbox = InputBox("Enter an Integer relating to the position of the textbox")

    val1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox " & targetbox).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    val2 = ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox " & (targetbox + 1)).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox " & targetbox).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = val2
    ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox " & (targetbox + 1)).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = val1
End Sub
```

You'll need to check the input to make sure you don't get errors. I'm also not convinced the names of the textboxes are reliable, but this should work as long as you aren't doing anything too crazy.

Comment: This approach is not reliable, for at least two reasons: 1) Looping `Shape` objects in a document often will *not* return them in the order they appear on the page - they'll be returned *in the order of their anchors*. 2) Word, itself, uses the names proposed, and will change these names at the drop of a hat - whenever a new drawing object TextBox is inserted between others. And keep in mind we don't *know* (yet) whether this is what's meant when the OP uses the term "textbox".

Comment: I mean, I did say all that in my post.